# ActiveX Control's Property doesn't bind to TagName in Wonderware InTouch

Tags: c#, activex, wonderware

I created activex control in C#.

I installed my activex control in Intouch Program

and i associated tag to property of activex control

the problem is the tag only can set property but not get property

in Wonderware Intouch Guide document, it explain like 'The property cannot change
the tagname's value because the property is non-bindable'

propery in C# is like this

```
public string Text1 
{
    get { return textBox1.Text; }
    set { textBox1.Text = value; }
}
```

i tried to make property bindable
by using '[bindable(true)], [Browsable(true)] etc..' in C#

but any setting doesn't work..

is it impossible activex control's property bind to Tag in InTouch?

Comment: Afaict, this requires the VB6-style of data binding.  Dead-easy in the VB6 IDE, just mark the property as "Property is data bound", but the plumbing that makes it work is not.  I think it requires the TypeFlagFuncFlags.FBindable attribute to be turned on in the type library declaration for the property and the implementing object to support the IPropertyNotifySink event interface.  .NET does not support any of this.  Time to go shopping, the product has not been named "Wonderware" for a very long time.  These days owned by Avevo, their sales literature mentions support for ".NET controls".

Comment: @sdb are you tied to using ActiveX controls? If you're using anything above 11.0 or so you should be able to rewrite your ActiveX as a .NET Client Control and have far more flexibility within Wonderware

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for answering. Thanks to you, I found out the detailed cause.

Comment: @Grambot Thank you for answering. I have to use the old version of the program.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/102533/Using-NET-with-Wonderware

Comment: @Hans Passant  Thank you for your kindness.
I have already fixed the problem by referring to the link on the site a week ago.
So I wrote the link in the answer, The answer was deleted.
Maybe I shouldn't write an external link in my answer or I didn't write down how to solve it in detail.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/102533/Using-NET-with-Wonderwared